# R Shiny - undo callModule

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to undo callModule?  The use case is I have a variable number of modules - the number responds to user selection.  Let's say the user chooses 10, then a different 10 - is there a way to remove the original 10?  Does it happen automatically?  I'm worried that memory is being occupied and not released.

It's a bit tricky creating an reprex, here's a snippet of what I mean though:

```
observeEvent(
  input$people
, {
  input$people %>% 
    walk(
      ~callModule(people_info_server, .x)
    )
  }
)
```

Every time the vector input$people changes, the module with people_info_server gets called on each element of input$people and generates a page of information for each person.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
observeEvent(
  input$people
, {
  remove_existing_calls(people_info_server) # Not sure how to define this function
  input$people %>% 
    walk(
      ~callModule(people_info_server, .x)
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you would have to create a "destructor" for your module and make sure that the client of the module (the "main app") calls the destructor at the right time. For example, let us suppose the module returns the destructor as a closure.

```r
library(shiny)

## module definition
module_with_destructor <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1:input$n)
  })
  destructor <- function() {
    # add more cleanup logic here
    output$plot <- NULL
  }
  return(destructor)
}
```

We now need to make sure that the main app executes the destructor when memory should be freed.

```r
## main app (client)
myenv <- new.env()
observeEvent(input$create_module, {
  if (is.null(myenv$destructor))
    myenv$destructor <- callModule(module_with_destructor, "module_id")
})

observeEvent(input$destroy_module, {
  if (!is.null(myenv$destructor))
    myenv$destructor()
})
```

Of course, you will have to implement some extra logic in order to use this idea with a dynamic number of modules. However, in your case you could just create a list that collects all the individual destructors and then iterate over them.

Comment: If I understand - this means setting all the child elements of the module to NULL - outputs, reactives, reactiveValues etc, so the modules are still there, just the child elements are all empty.

Comment: Yes. For outputs, it is recommended to set them to NULL in order to unregister all the underlying listeners. Observe-Functions (`observe()`, `observeEvent()`) have a return value with a `$destroy()` method. For `reactive()` and `reactiveValues()`, i am not sure if cleanup is necessary.